# Exporting Java Project from Eclipse, images are not shown

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I have an Eclipse Java project with about 10 external jar dependencies. It works fine in Eclipse, also I export it using tools like [ONE-JAR](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) and it works fine.

The strange problem I am facing is with images. I have all images in a package inside the project, and when exported they are included but they do not show in the running project?

I have no idea why? Strangely, in some JPanel text, I use HTML with embedded images using e.g:

```
URL url = myClass.class.getResource( "icons/icon.png");
```

and this works and shows those images at output, but the ones directly referenced by Java, e.g:

```
this.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/icons/icon.png"));
```

do not work. This same line of code works perfectly when running from Eclipse. Can you please suggest what could be the problem, or what should I do while exporting this project. Should I switch to Ant or Maven???

Comment: It looks like that second code is loading from the file system, not from the classpath (note how it starts with "src/"). This will work in Eclipse, because there is a "src" directory under the project root directory (which is the current working directory when you run your program from Eclipse).

Comment: Concur with @Thilo, solution is to try `"/icons/icon.png"` there (absolute path in jar).

Comment: @Thilo, oh ok let me try this, thank you

Comment: One question, if my class is say in pacakage gui/graph; and my images are in gui/grpah/icons; so from this class so i have to give complete path: gui/graph/icons or just the relative path: icons/

Comment: @Thilo, i have tried but then it does not work? is there something i am missing??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this:

```
URL url = myClass.class.getResource( "icons/icon.png");
this.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url));
```

`Toolkit` provides a method accepting a URL as well, see [`java.awt.Toolkit#getImage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getImage%28java.net.URL%29).

Comment: Thanks it works, i got it working by:
Images.class.getResource("icon.png"); where Images is a dummy class in the same package where all the icons are placed.